# Hammock nuget installation

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, nuget, nuget-package

Disclaimer: I'm new to .NET, nuget, windows store applications and so on.

I'm trying to follow [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6) tutorial to create a Twitter-based universal windows app.

But I can't install Hammock, it keeps getting me:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Impossibile installare il pacchetto 'Hammock 1.3.1'. Si sta tentando di eseguire l'installazione in un progetto destinato a   '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', ma il 
pacchetto non contiene riferimenti ad assembly o file di dati compatibili con il framework. Per ulteriori informazioni, contattare l'autore del pacchetto.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Hammock
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

The italian part say something like "I can't install Hammock because the package doesn't contain references to assembly or files compatible with the framework".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hammock does not have any assemblies that are compatible with the .NETCore target framework (Windows Store). It has assemblies for:

.NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0
Silverlight 4
Silverlight 4 + Windows Phone 7
Silverlight 4 + Windows Phone 7.1

To get it to work I suspect you will have to create a Windows Phone Silverlight project instead of a Windows Store project.